# Creation of child viewmodels in a parent viewmodel - mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm quite new to MVVM and with all the different opinions on MVVM it's hard for me to determine what is right / true.

Bit of background - at the moment I am developing an app using the WinUI 3 template from the template studio. This has dependency injection setup. All viewmodels / views are added as transient. They are created when required. When creating a page through the studio, it automatically adds the page + viewmodel where required.

Now I have a few occasions in my application where I have a master-details situation. I want to have a few 'configurations', when a user selects one, they can view & edit this configuration's properties.

My model classes are in a different project, part of them are the configuration classes which are POCO's and I would like not to implement INPC in.

So what I do is where required I wrap my model with a viewmodel using the functions provided by the community toolkit mvvm (one of the SetProperty overloads).

The profile can contain collections. These also exist in the model. For some of them I've created ViewModel classes, because they have some extra properties that I want to control in the UI, but are irrelevant for the model.

Now the part where I'm not sure what to do. Where do I create the viewmodels that represent collection elements?

At the moment I have a parent viewmodel which takes the parent configuration object from a service, and then converts the collection items to collectionItemViewModels and puts them in an ObservableCollection and then displays them. This works fine when binding directly to the nested viewmodels properties from the parent view, but I can also create a separate view and set its datacontext.

Is this good practice to do it like this?

Does anyone know of any good MVVM examples for this situation?

Or is there just something I am understanding very wrong?

Comment: There is no good practise for something with models where you need something more - it depends. There are some rules you should follow but most of them are common and not mvvm related